# Pass image url from one page to another in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I am fetching data from database table and showing result in HTML table. What I want to achieve is that, there is image column in every row, and every image is fetched from its URL (stored in database).  I am opening an image in new tab whenever it is clicked.

My question is that, how can I store url of image so that on the next page I don't want to show that real url?

The next page will look like this link:

> www.example.com/full_size_image.php

and add

> img tag

there to show that page

how can I store that specific image url when someone click on it?

```
  <img src= "<?php echo $_SESSION['link'] ;">
```

My current code is :

```
while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$result['c']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['UserName']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['UserProblemKeyword']."</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href ='".$result['UserProblemPicture']."' target='_blank'><img src='".$result['UserProblemPicture']."' height='62' width='62'> </a> </td>";           
            echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: is the image always the same or not

Comment: always different  image link

Comment: there 2 ways;- 1. use the `$_GET['image_id']` or use `session`

Comment: can i hide real link from URL ?

Comment: yes, use the `www.domain.com/full_size_image.php?img=id` then check the value, if its true load the image using `if(isset($_GET['image_id'])){//load real img from the database}`

Comment: i s there way to encrypt the link on one page and send it to another page and decrypt it ?

Comment: demo link : https://manybot-files.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/464156144097584/ca/2018/08/23/c9635c501280868fa6e6c415d9df9525/40046255_269713330305307_1118777154553774080_n

Comment: for that link, you will need to use the .htaccess file to manipulate you links as in your demo.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameter via the GET Request?
So instead of directing to just /full_size_image.php direct to
/full_size_image.php?img=filename.png

then in your php code for /full_size_image.php
You can fetch the file name via

```
<?php
 $img = isset($_GET['img']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['img']) : "";
 if ($img == "") {
    //img not set
 }
 //do whatever with the filename
```

Comment: So index the entry in the DB with a hash of the filename and use that instead of the real one?

Comment: is there any other way ? please

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "real url" 2) You can use a POST request if you want to hide it from the address bar but it will not hide it from parameters if you open up the network inspector.

Comment: i s there way to encrypt the link on one page and send it to another page and decrypt it ?

Comment: demo link : https://manybot-files.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/464156144097584/ca/2018/08/23/c9635c501280868fa6e6c415d9df9525/40046255_269713330305307_1118777154553774080_n

Comment: Just use a hash to reference the image from the database & pass it through a get request. Or use the auto increment ID